# Use one attribute only once in scikit-learn decision tree in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am using scikit-learn to create a decision tree, and its working like a charm. I would like to achieve one more thing: to make the tree to split on an attribute only once.

The reason behind this is because of my very strange dataset. I use a noisy dataset, and i am really interested in the noise as well. My class outcomes are binary let say [+,-]. I have a bunch of attributes with numbers mostly in the range of (0,1).

When scikit-learn creates the tree it splits on attributes multiple times, to make the tree "better". I understand that in this way the leaf nodes become more pure, but thats not the case i would like to achieve.

The thing i did was to define cutoffs for every attribute by counting the the information gain in different cutoffs, and choosing the maximum. In this way with "leave-one-out" and "1/3-2/3" cross validation techniques i get better results then the original tree.

The problem is that when i try to automatize this, i run into a problem  around the lower and upper bound e.g. around 0 and 1 because most of the elements will be under/upper that and  i get really high informational gain, cause one of the sets are pure, even if it only contains 1-2% of the full data.

All in all i would like to do something to make scikit-learn to only split on an attribute once.

If it cannot be done, do you guys have any advice how to generate those cutoffs in a nice way?

Comment: I wonder if you can achieve what you want by tuning `min_samples_leaf`, `min_samples_split` or `min_weight_fraction_leaf`.

Comment: Is it indeed possible as the OP describes?

Comment: I havebt found a way with sckit, i wrote my own methods

Comment: Do you really want to use each attribute only once? What's wrong if the same feature x_i is used both in the left and right subtrees? If you want to avoid overfitting, you could use gradient boosting with very small trees instead of a single tree.

Comment: Have you tried just using logistic regression? by definition it will use every attribute only once.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question briefly, no, there is no built-in parameter to do this in `sklearn`. I tried to do the same a year ago, so I opened an [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/19969) requesting the addition of this feature.

`sklearn` builds nodes by randomly picking `max_features` features from the training dataset and searching for the cutoff that reduces the loss function the most. This exact same process is ran iteratively until some stopping criteria is met (`max_depth`, `min_samples_leaf`, etc.).

Hence, every feature **always** has the same probability of being picked, regardless of whether or not it has been used before.

If you're up for it, you can [edit the source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13a/sklearn/tree/_classes.py#L607) of the classifier. In essence, all you need to do is drop the feature that minimizes the loss function after it has been chosen to build a node. That way, the algorithm will be unable to pick that feature again when taking a new sample of `max_features` features.

Answer (score 0):

I am not giving a method to directly deal with stopping the Classifier from using a feature multiple times. (Although you could do it by defining your own [splitter](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx) and wiring it in, it is a lot of work.)

I would suggest making sure that you are balancing your classes in the first place, take a look at the `class_weight` parameter for details. That should help a lot in your issue. But if that does not work you can still enforce that there are no leafs having too small weight in them using the `min_weight_fraction_leaf` or similar parameters as suggested by [maxymoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839957/maxymoo).